# Does every uncountable subsets has a limit point implies the topological space is Lindel$\ddot{\text{o}}$f?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, soft-question, normed-spaces, lindelof-spaces

Let $(X, \tau) $ be a topological space. If $(X, \tau) $ is Lindel$\ddot{\text{o}}$f then any uncountable subsets of $X$ has a limit point.

I want to know about the converse.

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4463468/977780) , i came to know about an important class of topological spaces( separable Banach spaces) where every uncountable sets has a limit point.But here it doesn't help us to provide any new information as any separable Banach space is again a Lindel$\ddot{\text{o}}$f.

My question : Suppose any uncountable subsets of $X$ has a limit point . Does this implies $(X, \tau) $ is lindel$\ddot{\text{o}}$f ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no.  The answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164826/how-to-prove-that-the-space-omega-1-times-r-has-countable-extent) shows that $\mathbb{R} \times \omega_1$ has the property that every uncountable subset has a limit point.  However, $\mathbb{R} \times \omega_1$ is not Lindelöf because it continuously maps onto $\omega_1$, continuous surjections preserve being Lindelöf, and $\omega_1$ is not Lindelöf.